# Can't seem to get the from <asp:Literal </asp:Literal> property in Web forms

Tags: webforms

Could someone please pin point me to what i'm doing wrong?
Basically all i need to  is get the text from my  property but for some reason it always returns as null.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            orderId.Text = "4567";
        }




 protected void UpdateOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        var getOrderId = orderId.Text; //always returns null here
    }
```

front end:

```
        <p>
        <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="orderId"> Order Id: </asp:Label>
        <asp:Literal ID="orderId" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </p>  << the orderId is displayed in the browser


  <asp:Button ID="updateBtn" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateOrder"/>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

at the top of my page. I removed it and boom it works

Comment: Accept your own answer if possible. Save people from looking at an answered question. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a control somewhere else on your page called **order**?

Your literal is called **orderId**

You're pulling a value from something called **order**.

Try:-

```
 protected void UpdateOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var getOrderId = orderId.Text; //always returns null here
 }
```

Comment: sorry that was my error when typing the question.. i have amended question ..i'm pullingmy value from orderId